# winfont.sty not found on mactex

Tags: fonts, mactex, sublime-text

I'm trying to build a model here with Sublime + MacTex + Skim
But I get this message: winfont.sty not found

1. I looked at the winfont readme (http://repositorios.cpai.unb.br/ctan/fonts/winfonts/README) but I'm not sure whether I'm able to use this with my OS (Mavericks)
2. I located the texmf-local (at least I believe I did) under /usr/local/texlive
3. But I cannot follow steps 2 and 3 now...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!
Rafael

Comment: First, do you really need/want to do this? You have substitutes for those fonts already available in MacTeX. Moreover, that package is based on XP fonts which are older and likely to be less generally useful than others you can use more easily. If you really must use that package for some reason, you first need those fonts in truetype format. Then you need to ignore most of those instructions and install them. [I don't agree with those instructions anyway but that could be a MiKTeX difference. In particular, I would **not** add lines to the map file or use `updmap(-sys)` for truetype.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE by the way. Could you explain why you think you want or need to use that package and those fonts? Also, what do you mean by a 'model'? If you are trying to compile a document, please provide the code of a small, complete document demonstrating the issue. (A Minimal (non-)Working Example.) Generally, all questions should include an M(n-)WE.

Comment: hello
thank you for the answer!
Well, I need this for my final thesis in graduation. I have a "model", a standard document which I intend to use.
Actually, this model has some problems (it only allows one author) but still is the best I have for now

Comment: What is the requirement exactly? I'm guessing it is not that you must use `winfonts`. For example, do they specify particular fonts you need to use? If so, does your thesis need to actually use those fonts or is it enough to use fonts which look like them? I ask because some of these things are a lot easier than others. If 'look alikes' are good enough, telling us which fonts they specify will allow us to tell you how to make your document look right. If they will actually check the fonts in the electronic document, knowing how they are specified is important. Also, is XeLaTeX an option?

Comment: Hi! Indeed, I just commented the line and the problem was solved : ) The true is that I'm beginning to deal with latex now and I really have no idea what does what. There are no requirements for the fonts, but I was afraid that the document wouldn't compile if I didn't have the correct fonts. Anyway, thank you very much, for now my problem is solved